# Getting segmentation fault when not specifying PEM file fo SSL

Tags: c, mongodb, openssl, mongo-c-driver

I'm using monoc 1.2.0 successfully,
I'm now trying to add an SSL enabled connection in a two of modes:

1. Only require SSL no certificate check
2. Provide certificate and verify it including hostname

For 1 I get segmentation fault:

```
#0 0x00002ac83368e3c8 in ssl23_connect () from libarepbase.so
#1 0x00002ac83aedb8fc in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
#2 0x00002ac83ac78423 in mongoc_stream_tls_do_handshake () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#3 0x00002ac83ac527f3 in mongoc_async_cmd_tls_setup () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#4 0x00002ac83ac5226c in _mongoc_async_cmd_phase_setup () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#5 0x00002ac83ac5241d in mongoc_async_cmd_run () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#6 0x00002ac83ac51dbc in mongoc_async_run () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#7 0x00002ac83ac6f47c in mongoc_topology_scanner_work () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#8 0x00002ac83ac6d4d8 in _mongoc_topology_run_scanner () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#9 0x00002ac83ac6d5f4 in mongoc_topology_select () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#10 0x00002ac83ac59351 in mongoc_cluster_select_by_optype () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#11 0x00002ac83ac5e126 in _mongoc_cursor_next () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#12 0x00002ac83ac5e635 in mongoc_cursor_next () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#13 0x00002ac83ac54e19 in _mongoc_client_command_simple_with_hint () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#14 0x00002ac83ac54eeb in mongoc_client_command_simple () from libmongoc-1.0.so.0
#15 0x00002ac83a80d983 in mongodb_new_client () from libarepmongodb.so
```

For 2 I get:
`No suitable servers found ('serverselectiontryonce' set)`
and error code: 120414

The server conf is:

```
net:
    ssl:
        mode: requireSSL                            
        PEMKeyFile: /etc/mongodb-ssl.pem
```

and the cert has the correct hostname (server CN).
The code looks a bit like this with `ssl=true` in the url to start the client and the line that updates `pem_file` is not being executed for mode 1:

```
mongoc_ssl_opt_t ssl_opts = *mongoc_ssl_opt_get_default();
ssl_opts.weak_cert_validation = TRUE;
ssl_opts.pem_file = "path to pem here";
mongoc_client_set_ssl_opts(client, &ssl_opts);
bool ret = FALSE;
bson_t cmd = BSON_INITIALIZER;
bson_t reply;

BSON_APPEND_INT32 (&cmd, "buildInfo", 1);

ret = mongoc_client_command_simple (client, "admin", &cmd, NULL, &reply, error);`
```

When I run:
`/mongo host/admin  -u user -p pass --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates`
I can login but I see:
`2017-03-28T18:14:36.149+0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate`
But I guess this is since I'm using self signed and `ssl_opts.weak_cert_validation = TRUE` should handle it?

Comment: *"... and the cert has the correct hostname (server CN)"* - ***`CN=www.example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) Two other items of interest: (1) TLS 1.0 and above; and (2) Server Name Indication (SNI).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome input regarding the SSL setup, but there's still an issue with the mongoc driver, if the pem_file argument is left empty I get a seg fault even If I don't want to use a pem file